# What does 50/50 mean in cluster quorum?

Tags: windows, cluster, failover, clustering

What does 50/50 mean in cluster quorum?

Link to table: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/concepts/quorum#cluster-quorum-overview

Answer (score 1):

It means there's a 50% chance of survival, depending on *which* node fails, because when you're left with only two nodes, one of them becomes more important than the other.

That's explained in the same article under "Dynamic quorum behavior", and under "Examples".

> **Two nodes without a witness**
>
> One node's vote is zeroed, so the majority vote is determined out of a total of 1 vote.
> If the non-voting node goes down unexpectedly, the survivor has 1/1 and the cluster survives.
> If the voting node goes down unexpectedly, the survivor has 0/1 and the cluster goes down.